# NEAR NEAR CLI has a minor update available 2.1.1 → 2.2.0 │ │ Run yarn add near-cli to avoid unexpected behavior (does not resolve)

Tags: nearprotocol

Running the exercises from: /starter--near-sdk-as
yields ...

NEAR CLI has a minor update available 2.1.1 → 2.2.0   │
│   Run yarn add near-cli to avoid unexpected behavior

Running the yarn command as instructed - does NOT resolve or remove the "recommendation/message".

Pls advise

This is run under WSL2 n Ubuntu 20.04.3 under Windows X (with its Bash Terminal, NOT powershell, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

**NEAR CLI is most likely installed globally.**

If you post a screenshot of the message here, my guess is there is a global flag included.

The command should probably be something like `npm install -g near-cli`

If using yarn then I think it's something like `yarn global add near-cli`

---

If this is not the case and you actually are using `near-cli` as a local project dependency then you can do the following:

- delete the `node_modules` folder
- delete `package-lock.json` file (or `yarn.lock` file)
- update `package.json` with the new `near-cli` version
- run `npm install` (or `yarn`) to bring it all back

Comment: SS from VSCode bash terminal ... How do I add my screen shot?